# How to change registry value for (default) with install4j

Tags: install4j

I am trying to change the value of a registry key with install4j.  Its a value that shows as (default) in the registry editor.

If I use an action to "Set a value in the windows registry" and specify the "value name" as "(default)", then I get two default values.  Or at least two values that have that name displayed.  Any only the first (original) one is used.

If I use an action to "Read a value from the Windows registry" and specify the "value name" as either "(default)" or blank, then I get an error.

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.registry.ReadRegistryValueAction 
[ID xx]: Execute action not successful after 0 ms
```

Has anyone been able to do this?  Clearly default values are special, but I cannot figure out to get at them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default value is accessed by passing a null pointer to the Windows registry functions. With the actions in the install4j, there is no way to specify a null string, but you should be able to do this by using the API:

https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api/com/install4j/api/windows/WinRegistry.html

and passing `null` as the `valueName` parameter to `WinRegistry.setValue`.